# Is it possible to delete or insert frames into the C# call stack?

Tags: c#, callstack

Using `StackTrace` I can get the stack frames. My question is whether it is possible to manipulate the call stack in C#? More specifically: Is it possible...

- to insert a frame into the call stack? or
- to delete a frame from it?

Comment: Please define *manipulate*. What kind of manipulations do you need? Retrieve?

Comment: What do you mean by "manipulation"? Only the output that you get by say "Environment.StackTrace" or actually divert the calls? From inside any managed code, or by hosting the CLR yourself. Please provide more context and what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: Now that you've edited and added the second paragraph it is clearer what you mean, I'm voting for reopening.

Comment: It would be interesting to know why you would want to manipulate the call stack.  It seems like a bad idea that would make tracking the execution even worse than the old days of using Goto statements.

Comment: It is not so easy to explain the reason. I have an idea that would simplified the .net based web development in some ways.

Comment: what is the outcome you want to generate? I mean, ok, you "manipulate" the call stack to do what? change how the execution point returns from functions? or you just want to change the way the StackTrace is displayed?

Comment: Do you want to manipulate the *actual* call stack? Or just massage a StackTrace object? (Which only *represents* a call stack.)

Answer (score 4):

Stack is a very internal component of program's runtime. Having the ability to alter it would make it possible to:

- Make almost unrestricted goto's. Something that is considered a very bad programming practice and is not possible even in PHP. Debugging such thing would be a complete mess.
- Inject code on method returns. This may be useful, but is already covered by aspect oriented tools, like **PostSharp** or **Spring.NET**, which allow you to do this in clean and predictable way. And they cover much more cases than just method returns.

Thus, I do not think there is any programming language that allows you to manipulate stack explicitly. It would make things very messy and any benefits it may produce are already covered by Aspect-Oriented-Programming. I bet **AOP** will make you able to achieve what you want.

Comment: I agree, if weaving is what you need, AOP is what the OP should look for.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to manipulate the stack in Smalltalk, but I don't think it is possible in C#.

Answer (score 1):

StackTrace class doesn't support this kind of manipulation. Frames are read only as per msdn (only GetFrame, GetFrames methods are available).

To see how the class is created by framework you can have a look directly into source code of the class.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. [The Stack Is An Implementation Detail](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx).
Moreover, the ability to manipulate the stack will bring a LOT of security/consistency issues. This is why manipulating the stack is a bad practice/a security bug even when you can do it (in C, for example). For example,the infamous "buffer overflow" category of security issues spring exactly from this: the ability to insert a "goto", a new stack frame, into the code, so that upon return a malicious payload is executed instead of the legitimate calling function.

But then, why would you like to do it? Given a real goal, we could better reason how to do that, and suggest good alternatives

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can via Reflection. 
Ultimately it's a string.

The following is an exception class for logging `Javascript` exceptions with the javascript stacktrace as a C# exception, `preserving the original stack trace`.

```
using System.Reflection;
    public class JsException : Exception
    {
        static readonly FieldInfo _stackTraceString = typeof(Exception).GetField("_stackTraceString", BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        public JsException(string error, string stack)
            : base(error)
        {
            _stackTraceString.SetValue(this, stack);
        }
    }
```